# Google Sheets API Java program, works on one machine and not the other - 401 Au

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I've got a working basic Java App that uploads some data to a google sheets file of mine.

I uploaded it to a git client, pulled it to my other computer, and it doesn't work on that with a 401

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at App.main(App.java:71)
```

Any idea what could be different between the two machines? I understand it that if I'm using the same client_secret.json, it should be irrelevant which machine I'm on?

UDPATE 1:

ok, some extra info - i just tried my project at work on my work laptop and it worked fine! On first run it opened a browser window and asked me which google account I wanted to use, I chose the correct one, and that worked. On the laptop I have that didn't work, I wasn't given that option (that I remember) so how can I reset the google account that has been used to authenticate against?

I saw this in my cmd line

```
Please open the following address in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=blah-notputtingmyrealid.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:42299/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's working on your previous computer, the issue might be concerning the location of your `client_secret.json`. If you check the [Java Quickstart setup](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java), there's a part where you need to download the JSON file and place it on your working directory. Since, you're on a new machine, that file is now missing.

> g. Click the file_download (Download JSON) button to the right of the
>   client ID.
>
> h. Move this file to your working directory and rename it
>   client_secret.json.

Or the access token has expired.

Comment: No this is definitely in the right place. I committed it to the repo!

Comment: Ok, try this, create a new Java Quickstart following the setup on this OTHER PC of yours. Start fresh (new client_json, new everything). if it works, then that says something.

Comment: Did you create a fresh project? The issue here is that of client_secret.json or your access token has expired (which needs a refresh token implementation). Those are the 2 possible things I can see.

Comment: Not a new project, but it was a new set of credentials under the of project, still i got a new secret. I thought about it expiring and needing refreshing, but my other laptop that i got the project working on initially, still works, so I'd say that it can't have expired?

Comment: As one who's played with Google APIs, I'd say Google API has a default duration of 1 hour. After 1 hour, that access token expires unless you have a refresh token implementation. And basing from your error logs, it seems that's the problem you're facing, an expired access token.

Comment: ok, some extra info - i just tried my project at work on my work laptop and it worked fine! On first run it opened a browser window and asked me which google account I wanted to use, I chose the correct one, and that worked. On the laptop I have that didn't work, I wasn't given that option (that I remember) so how can I reset the google account that has been used to authenticate against?

Comment: did you by any chance modify the default scope (SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)?

Comment: No. And as I have it working on *another* new machine, it must be down to which google account it's trying to use, on the broken one. I need to somehow disassociate which google account is being used.